# stepUp(1) , stepDown(1) not working in IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

HTML5 `stepUp(1)` and `stepDown(1)` are not working in IE.
Here is my code:

```
<div class = "col-sm-3">
    <div class = "waist">             
        <p class = "waist-measure" id="mens-bottom-waist">Waist</p>
        <a class = "waist-plus btn" onclick="waistPlus()">+</a>
        <a class = "waist-minus btn " onclick="waistMinus()">-</a>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
function waistPlus() {
    document.getElementById("waist").stepUp(1);
}
    function waistPlus() {
    document.getElementById("waist").stepDown(1);
}
</script>
```

Comment: please share code what you trying...

Comment: How would giving two functions with different behavior the same name work? My guess is "not correctly." Among other things...

Answer (score 2):

The methods `stepUp` and `stepDown` are only defined on `<input>` elements with `type="number"`. The element with `id="waist"` in your document isn't of that type, so the methods don't work.

Answer (score 0):

The methods stepUp and stepDowm are not supported by IE.
You can achieve this by using this:

```js
var my_value = 1;
function stepup(){
  var cur_val = document.querySelector("#quantity").value;
  if(cur_val == 1 || cur_val > 1){
    //Parse Current Value to Int
    my_value = (parseInt(cur_val) + 1);
   document.querySelector("#quantity").value = my_value;
  }
}

function stepdown(){
 var cur_val = document.querySelector("#quantity").value;
 if(cur_val > 1){
  //Parse Current Value to Int
  my_value = (parseInt(cur_val) - 1);
 document.querySelector("#quantity").value = my_value;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="quantity" autocomplete="off" step="1" value="1"/>
<button type="button" onclick="stepup();">StepUp</button>
<button type="button" onclick="stepdown();">StepDown</button>
```

Hope this will help